# Who was the first to mention the nine problem?

Tags: set-theory

When Cantor published his seminal diagonal argument, he used binary code and did not distinguish the real numbers 0.1000… and 0.0111… Later, Koenig found a way to save the diagonal argument in binary digits (a reference would be appreciated). Meanwhile, the most popular form is to use decimal digits.

My main question: Who was the first person to mention that in the diagonal argument digits should not be replaced by 9's because of 0.1999⋯ = 0.2000… ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first mention of the "nine-problem" was by Felix Klein, Vorträge über ausgewählte Fragen der Elementargeometrie, Teubner 1895, p. 42.
http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/t/text/text-idx?c=umhistmath;idno=ACV2370.0001.001

Comment: I was unable to find the relevant section on the page you cite; Can you reproduce it?

Comment: Klein writes on p. 42: 1 = 0.99...9.... Um der dadurch bewirkten Unbestimmtheit zu entgehen, setzen wir ein für alle Mal fest, dass wir unendliche Neuner-Reihen vermeiden wollen.

Answer (score 2):

> When Cantor published his seminal diagonal argument, he used binary code and did not distinguish the real numbers 0.1000… and 0.0111…

This is **not** relevant for the proof.

See :

- Joseph Dauben, [Georg Cantor : His Mathematics and Philosophy of the Infinite](https://books.google.it/books?id=-cpFeTPJXDIC&printsec=frontcover) (1990)

and

- José Ferreiros, [Labyrinth of thought : A history of set theory and its role in modern mathematics](https://books.google.it/books?id=-WL0BwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) (2ed 2007)

For detailed discussion of Cantor's proofs:

> 1873 proof: [Dauben](https://books.google.it/books?id=-cpFeTPJXDIC&pg=PA50) page 50 and [Ferreiros](https://books.google.it/books?id=-WL0BwAAQBAJ&pg=PA179) page 179.
>
> 1877 proof: [Ferreiros](https://books.google.it/books?id=-WL0BwAAQBAJ&pg=PA190) page 190-2. See page 190, for the presumibely source of the misconception.
>
> 1891 proof (the *diagonalization* one): [Dauben](https://books.google.it/books?id=-cpFeTPJXDIC&pg=PA165) page 165 and [Ferreiros](https://books.google.it/books?id=-WL0BwAAQBAJ&pg=PA287) page 287.

---

For an early textbook version of the diagonal proof, see:

- [William Henry Young](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Henry_Young) & Grace Chisholm Young, [The Theory of Sets of Points](https://books.google.it/books?id=TIzfPwAACAAJ), (1906) page 43 : decimal notation used, and the rule for "diagonalization" is :

> "we now define a number [...] $b=0.b_1b_2b_3 \ldots$, where $b_r$ is never the same as $a_{rr}$."

---

Regarding the purported "mistake" in the diagonal proof, see e.g. Robert Gray [Georg Cantor and Transcendental Numbers](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/images/upload_library/22/Ford/Gray819-832.pdf), *The American Mathematical Monthly*, vol. 101, 1994, page 823.

The "general" theorem consider an enumeration of an infinite sequnce of infinite strings of symbols, with only two symbols : $m$ or $w$.

The proof does **not** rely on any property of real numbers (or their representation).

It is easily "applied" to the real numbers through their binary representation.

In the case of number with a "dual" representation, both representation must be included into the enumeration.

We can consider a simplified case :

> $$a_1=0.000 \ldots$$
>
> $$a_2=0.011 \ldots$$
>
> $$a_3=0.100 \ldots$$
>
> $$\ldots$$

and apply Young's procedure; we will get :

> > $$b=0.101 \ldots$$

because: $b_1 \ne a_{11}=0$, $b_2 \ne a_{22}=1$, $b_3 \ne a_{33}=0$.

The presence of $a_2$ and $a_3$, that are two "dual" representation of the same number, does not invalidate the diagonalization.

With this simple example we see that also if two members of the list, say $a_n$ and $a_m$, are two distinct *representations* of the same *number* we have that :

> $b \ne a_n$, because $b_n \ne a_{nn}$

and :

> $b \ne a_m$, because $b_m \ne a_{mm}$

and this "works" irrespectively of the fact that $a_n=a_m$ or not.

Comment: You are wrong. See Cantor's original paper [G. Cantor: "Über eine elementare Frage der Mannigfaltigkeitslehre", Jahresbericht der DMV I (1890-91) 75-78]. He used binary digits m and w and did not bother whether mwww... or wmmm... are identical. Further I have reason to believe that Young is not the first source of the nine-problem.

Comment: @Mauro Allegranza: Gray is completely wrong. Cantor's diagonal number differs from all $n$-digit numbers for every $n$ but does never complete a digit sequence of a transcendental number. Proof: For every digit $d_n$ we can prove that it is not completing an infinite sequence.